# Gronwall-type inequality assumption implies function is identically zero

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

After stating and proving a version of Gronwall's lemma for continuous functions (as in [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657170/understanding-this-proof-of-gronwalls-inequality?rq=1)), the author of the book I'm reading suggests trying to prove a related fact as an exercise.

Suppose that

$$ \phi(t) \le \int_{t_0}^t \psi(s)\phi(s) ds, $$

where $t_0 \le t \le t_0 + a$, and the functions $\phi(t), \psi(t) \ge 0$ are continuous. The exercise is to show that this implies $\phi(t) = 0$ for all $t \in [t_0, t_0+a]$.

I can see why this might be true (by picturing what happens if $\phi(t)$ is not identically zero),  but I am struggling to prove this. The given proof of Gronwall's lemma does not work for this assumption. It looks as if an integral form of the MVT may help, but I was not able to make it work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: First, get rid of that delta_1, you can set it to 1 without loss.

Comment: Good point, I've removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Let $\Phi(t) = \displaystyle\int_{t_0}^t \psi(s)\phi(s)\,ds$. Note now that $\phi(t)\le\Phi(t)$ and so $\Phi'(t) \le \psi(t)\Phi(t)$.

Comment: I can see how this would give the conclusion using a differential version of Gronwall's lemma. However, this exercise comes after proving an integral version, namely the one mentioned in [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657170/understanding-this-proof-of-gronwalls-inequality?rq=1). If I understand correctly, that version will not suffice, which suggests to me that the author is looking for a direct way to prove this.

Comment: @MMFTSBU: It suffices to integrate the differential inequality Ted proved here, as if it were an identity, using an integrating factor. The conclusion that Psi=0 is quickly reached.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro don't you mean $\phi=0$?